# How to show the data stored in the blockchain to the client side app

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, javascript, ganache

I wrote this contract for an 'Online Birth and Death Registration System' that stores data to the blockchain and now I'd like to know how i can retrieve the data I store so I can display it on another page on the client side.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

contract Obdrs {

    uint public regCount;
    uint256 dateOfBirth; //save date as unix timestamp or use a string
    string gender;
    string fullName;
    string placeOfBirth;
    string motherFullname;
    string motherNrc;
    string fatherFullname;
    string fatherNrc;
    string bo; //birthOccurence
    string permanentAddress; //address
    string contactNumber;
    //... with all of your properties

    struct form1 {

    uint256 dateOfBirth; //save date as unix timestamp or use a string
    string gender;
    string fullName;
    string placeOfBirth;
    string motherFullname;
    string motherNrc;
}    
    struct form2 {
    string fatherFullname;
    string fatherNrc;
    string bo; //birthOccurence
    string permanentAddress; //address
    string contactNumber;
    //... with all of your properties
}

          mapping(uint => form1) public forms1;
          mapping(uint => form2) public forms2;

        event formsReg1(
    uint id,
    uint256 dateOfBirth, //save date as unix timestamp or use a string
    string gender,
    string fullName,
    string placeOfBirth,
    string motherFullname,
    string motherNrc
  );     

      event formsReg2(
    uint id,
    string fatherFullname,
    string fatherNrc,
    string bo, //birthOccurence
    string permanentAddress, //address
    string contactNumber
    //... with all of your properties

  );


    function storeBirthCertificate1(uint256 _dateOfBirth, string memory _gender, 
    string memory _fullName, string memory _placeOfBirth, string memory _motherFullname, 
    string memory _motherNrc) public {

            regCount ++;
    forms1[regCount] = form1(_dateOfBirth, _gender, _fullName,
                             _placeOfBirth, _motherFullname, _motherNrc);
    emit formsReg1(regCount, _dateOfBirth, _gender, _fullName,
                             _placeOfBirth, _motherFullname, _motherNrc);


    }

     function storeBirthCertificate2(string memory _fatherFullname,
    string memory _fatherNrc, string memory _bo, string memory _permanentAddress, 
    string memory _contactNumber) public {

            regCount ++;
    forms2[regCount] = form2(_fatherFullname, _fatherNrc, _bo,
                             _permanentAddress, _contactNumber);
    emit formsReg2(regCount, _fatherFullname, _fatherNrc, _bo,
                             _permanentAddress, _contactNumber);


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two options:

- Since your two mapping have public access modifier, you can query pass them a specific index and you'll retrieve a tuple about `form1`/`form2` struct of specific index that you passed;
- Second way is to wrote a `getter` methods for both your structs and query into them passing into getter function the index of tuple stored using `storeBirthCertificate1` or  `storeBirthCertificate2` functions.
  An example about this last case is:

  ```
  // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
  pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.9.0;

  contract Obdrs {
   uint public regCount;
   uint256 dateOfBirth; //save date as unix timestamp or use a string
   string gender;
   string fullName;
   string placeOfBirth;
   string motherFullname;
   string motherNrc;
   string fatherFullname;
   string fatherNrc;
   string bo; //birthOccurence
   string permanentAddress; //address
   string contactNumber;
   //... with all of your properties

   struct form1 {
       uint256 dateOfBirth; //save date as unix timestamp or use a string
       string gender;
       string fullName;
       string placeOfBirth;
       string motherFullname;
       string motherNrc;
   }

   struct form2 {
       string fatherFullname;
       string fatherNrc;
       string bo; //birthOccurence
       string permanentAddress; //address
       string contactNumber;
       //... with all of your properties
   }

   mapping(uint => form1) private forms1;
   mapping(uint => form2) private forms2;

   event formsReg1(uint id, uint256 dateOfBirth, string gender, string fullName, string placeOfBirth, string motherFullname,string motherNrc);     
   event formsReg2(uint id, string fatherFullname, string fatherNrc, string bo, string permanentAddress, string contactNumber);


   function storeBirthCertificate1(uint256 _dateOfBirth, string memory _gender, string memory _fullName, string memory _placeOfBirth, string memory _motherFullname, string memory _motherNrc) public {
       regCount ++;
       forms1[regCount] = form1(_dateOfBirth, _gender, _fullName, _placeOfBirth, _motherFullname, _motherNrc);
       emit formsReg1(regCount, _dateOfBirth, _gender, _fullName, _placeOfBirth, _motherFullname, _motherNrc);
   }

    function storeBirthCertificate2(string memory _fatherFullname, string memory _fatherNrc, string memory _bo, string memory _permanentAddress, string memory _contactNumber) public {
       regCount ++;
       forms2[regCount] = form2(_fatherFullname, _fatherNrc, _bo, _permanentAddress, _contactNumber);
       emit formsReg2(regCount, _fatherFullname, _fatherNrc, _bo, _permanentAddress, _contactNumber);
   }

   function getBirthCertificateForm1(uint _index) external view returns(form1 memory) {
       return forms1[_index];
   }

   function getBirthCertificateForm2(uint _index) external view returns(form2 memory) {
       return forms2[_index];
   }
  }
  ```

Comment: Can you share your idea for the corresponding JavaScript code for the solidity contract above. Which includes functions to store and functions to read the stored data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use either web3js or ethersjs to communicate with blockchain from client side. It's documentation is fairly understandable to implement

Answer (score 0):

to retrive data from blockchain you can use javascript/python web3 library.
you will need `ABI` and `contract address` to call functions of smart contract.
Also you need an RPC provider (free tire is enough)

use methods : https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth-contract.html#id28

codes will look like this:

```
const Web3 = require("web3")
const web3 = new Web3(<RPC-Provider>)
abi=[{...ABI Code...}]
address="<your wallet address>"
async function getData(){
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address)
    let value=await contract.methods.retruceArray().call()
    console.log(value)
}
getData()
```

to put data, you need to put a little more codes and effort

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(<RPC provider link>)
const setting={
    from: "<your wallet address>",
    gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(210000),
    maxFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('40', 'gwei')),
    maxPriorityFeePerGas: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('40', 'gwei')),
}

async function interact(contractadddress,FunctionName,ABI,parms){
    let contract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, contractadddress)
    let result=await contract.methods[FunctionName](parms).send(setting)
        .then((receipt)=>{ return receipt})
        .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)})
    return result
}
```

you can also use etherum.js instade of web3.js

many youtube channels like hashlips, dappuniversity, moralis etc. may also helpful in learning DApp dev.